# How can update column of database by id (primary key)

Tags: database

I would like to update my database by `id`.

This is my database:

```
mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("mydb",contect.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ "MYTABLE "+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, mysms TEXT, deliver INTEGER,id INTEGER);");
mydatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + "MYTABLE" + " (mysms) VALUES ('"+date_time+"')");
mydatabase.close();
```

What would be the proper query to update the `mysms` column by `id`?

Comment: Have you tried something that hasn't worked yet?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the database table for AUTO increment of ID as primary number (integer).

Comment: It's ok,but i want update row mysms column by id   example :mydatabase.execaql("update"+"mytable"+"set mysms where  id_="12)